# Possible to remove HTML tags from keys in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I'm making a request to a database, and building an array, the keys of my array have HTML tags in them; I can not figure out how to remove the HTML but still keep the keys and their values.

I've tried matching RegEx, and slicing, which works for the most part, but when reconstructing, values get mismatched and put into wrong value holders.

**** EDIT: This is the regex used to get the names from the href tags.**
Note: The original array is store in tableDate.

```js
        let newnames = []
        Object.keys(tableData).forEach(function (key) {
            let byeHTML = key.match(/\>(.*?)</g)[0]
            noHMTLnames = byeHTML.slice(1, byeHTML.length -1)
            newtab.push(noHMTLnames)
            nametest = JSON.stringify(newtab)
        })
        console.log(nametest)
```

This is the array I'm working with

```js
[ '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2181524">Rum</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 11, Xanax: 0 },
  '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2272881">cliffyd</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 0, Xanax: 0 },
  '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2172188">BitMappedIn</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 4, Xanax: 0 },
  '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=767572">pilsner</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 3, Xanax: 0 },
  '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2179037">Bantor</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 10, Xanax: 0 },
  '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=536670">chef</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 0, Xanax: 0 },
  '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2283920">Yakob</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 0, Xanax: 0 } ]
```

And this is what I'd like to see:

```js
[ 'Rum': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 11, Xanax: 0 },
  'cliffyd': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 0, Xanax: 0 },
  'BitMappedIn': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 4, Xanax: 0 },
  'pilsner': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 3, Xanax: 0 },
  'Bantor': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 10, Xanax: 0 },
  'chef': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 0, Xanax: 0 },
  'Yakob': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 0, Xanax: 0 } ]
```

Comment: Show the regex to match the `Rum,cliff,...`

Comment: Your array incorrect format.

Comment: Your "array" should be an object, unless you want your "keys" to be strictly numerical.

Comment: The best solution is to clean the array at the server-side before sending it to the page. Notice also, that both the current and goal syntax is invalid (an array can't directly contain key value pairs).

Answer (score 2):

The given input and output is invalid. It should be object.You can use `Object.fromEntries()` to change the keys of the object. Use `map()` on `Object.entries()` and change the key.

```js
const obj = {'<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2181524">Rum</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 11, Xanax: 0 }, '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2272881">cliffyd</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 0, Xanax: 0 }, '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2172188">BitMappedIn</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 4, Xanax: 0 }, '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=767572">pilsner</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 3, Xanax: 0 }, '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2179037">Bantor</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 10, Xanax: 0 }, '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=536670">chef</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 0, Xanax: 0 }, '<a href = "http://www.torn.com/profiles.php?XID=2283920">Yakob</a>': { Refill: 0, SFAK: 0, FAK: 0, BloodBag: 0, Morphine: 0, Xanax: 0 } }

const matchKey = (str) => str.match(/>=?(.+)?</g)[0].slice(1,-1);
  
const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v]) => [matchKey(k),v]));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: This was almost perfect!!! All I had to do was change the `Object.fromEntries` to `Object.values`. Thank you so much @Maheer Ali!

Comment: @DanG Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: after playing with the snippet for a bit, I realized it's not quite what I'm looking for, but oh so close.
It's actually giving me an extremely confusing array lol

Comment: @DanG Your question contain input and output which is not possible in javascript. Your input and output have array but array can't have key value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot about this...
This is the route I ended up going with, works perfect for my usage.

```
fixedData = {};
for (let name in tableData) {
const stripHtml = name.match(/\>(.*?)</g)[0];
const playerName = stripHtml.slice(1, stripHtml.length - 1)
fixedData[playerName] = tableData[name]
}
```